# Integration testing with Nuxt and Jest

Tags: jasmine, jestjs, nuxt.js

I wish to render a page using Nuxt's `renderAndGetWindow` in order to test the values returned by my API.

Here's how I do it:

```
// Nuxt instance
let nuxt = null;
// Our page to test
let homePage = null;

beforeAll(async (done) => {
    // Configuration
    const rootDir = resolve(__dirname, '../..');
    let config = {};
    config = require(resolve(rootDir, 'nuxt.config.js'));
    config.rootDir = rootDir; // project folder
    config.env.isDev = false; // dev build
    config.mode = 'universal'; // Isomorphic application

    nuxt = new Nuxt(config);
    await new Builder(nuxt).build();
    nuxt.listen(3001, 'localhost');
    homePage = await nuxt.renderAndGetWindow('http://localhost:3001/');
  });
```

Which gives me 2 distinct errors:

> console.error node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmine/Env.js:157
>       Unhandled error
>
> console.error node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmine/Env.js:158
>       TypeError: setInterval(...).unref is not a function

And

> Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.
>
> ```
>  at mapper (node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queue_runner.js:41:52)
> ```

I get this ever since I switched from Ava to Jest.

Am I handling my rendering wrong?

Answer (score 4):

### unref

[The default test environment for `Jest` is a browser-like environment through `jsdom`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testenvironment-string).

`unref` is a special function provided by `Node`.  It is not implemented in browsers or in `jsdom`, but [it is implemented in the "node" test environment in `Jest`](https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/4622).

It looks like testing a `Nuxt` app requires both a `Node` environment to start a server, and a `jsdom` environment to test the resulting UI.

This can be done by setting the test environment to "node" and initializing a `window` using `jsdom` during the test setup.

### timeout

`Jest` will ["wait if you provide an argument to the test function, usually called `done`"](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#testname-fn-timeout).  This applies to test functions and setup functions like `beforeAll`.

Your `beforeAll` function has an argument `done` that is never called.  `Jest` will wait until either `done` is called or the timeout configured with [`jest.setTimeout`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestsettimeouttimeout) expires (defaults to 5 seconds).

You are using an `async` function and are using `await` on what looks to be the asynchronous part of the function so you don't need `done`.  Change your `beforeAll` function to not take any parameters and that will prevent `Jest` from waiting for `done` to be called.

In my tests starting the `Nuxt` server takes quite a while so you can pass a `timeout` value as an additional parameter to `beforeAll` to increase the timeout for just that function.

---

Here is an updated test with these changes:

```js
/**
 * @jest-environment node
 */
// TODO: Set the environment to "node" in the Jest config and remove this docblock

// TODO: Move this to a setup file
const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom');
const { window } = new JSDOM();  // initialize window using jsdom

const resolve = require('path').resolve;
const { Nuxt, Builder } = require('nuxt');

// Nuxt instance
let nuxt = null;
// Our page to test
let homePage = null;

beforeAll(async () => {
  // Configuration
  const rootDir = resolve(__dirname, '../..');
  let config = {};
  config = require(resolve(rootDir, 'nuxt.config.js'));
  config.rootDir = rootDir; // project folder
  config.env.isDev = false; // dev build
  config.mode = 'universal'; // Isomorphic application

  nuxt = new Nuxt(config);
  await new Builder(nuxt).build();
  nuxt.listen(3001, 'localhost');
  homePage = await nuxt.renderAndGetWindow('http://localhost:3001/');
}, 20000);  // Give the beforeAll function a large timeout

afterAll(() => {
  nuxt.close();
});

describe('homepage', () => {
  it('should do something', () => {
  });
});
```

Comment: Setting the env. to node seems to trigger problems since jsdom is needed (and is the default env.)

Comment: @Christopher yep, looks like testing `Nuxt` apps requires both a `Node` environment and a `jsdom` environment.  Answer updated.

Comment: upvoted! how will you test if GET / returns status code 200, do you need superagent or something?

Comment: @BrianAdams why does the process continue to run after the tests are complete?